# Odd Neural Net performance on 2 different machines

Tags: pytorch

So I have a neural net using pytorch, which I ran on my macbook pro (dual core 3.5GHz 16GB RAM), and my mac pro (8 core 3GHz, 64GB RAM). ON the macbook pro I was getting over 50 it/s whereas the mac pro was only getting about 20 it/s. Both were on 100% CPU usage, so the mac pro being slower doesn't make sense? Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: The first CPU can process more instructions per second in a single core (it has a larger clock) but that shouldn't be enough to make a 150% improvement in speed. You probably having problems with the way the model is been distributed to multiple cores.

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but looking at the clock speeds, the 8 Core has better cooling so actually they end up settling on very similar clocks speeds, the 8 core turbos to 3.4 Ghz and the 2 core to 3.5Ghz. Which I agree can't account for the different.